# no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Tags: html, regex, r, web-scraping, last.fm

I have the following code I don't know why I receive this error:

```
rm(list=ls())
require("XML")
# <a href="/music/The+Beatles/Sgt.+Pepper%27s+Lonely+Hearts+Club+Band" 
beatles = "http://www.last.fm/music/The+Beatles/"

beatles.albums.page = paste(sep="", beatles, "+albums")
lines = readLines(beatles.albums.page)
album.lines = grep(pattern="href.*link-reference", lines, value=TRUE)
album.names = sub(pattern=".*<h3>(.*)</h3>.*", replacement="\\1", x=album.lines)
album.names = gsub(pattern=" ", replacement="+", x=album.names)
album.names = gsub(pattern="'", replacement="%27", x=album.names)

for (album in album.names[1]) {
  print(album)
  album.link = paste(sep="", beatles, album)
  print(album.link)
  tables = readHTMLTable(album.link)

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: The line `readHTMLTable(album.link)` is causing the error.

Comment: What's the problem with it? How can it be fixed?

Comment: last.fm does have an API - http://www.last.fm/api - that would make this *much* cleaner than scraping.

Comment: Do they have an R script for their API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
readHTMLTable(album.link)
```

is causing the error. Try changing it to

```
tables = readHTMLTable(album.link, header = FALSE)
```

But it still gives you the warning:

```
Warning message:
In readLines(beatles.albums.page) :
  incomplete final line found on 'http://www.last.fm/music/The+Beatles/+albums'
```

Which you can get rid with

```
readLines(beatles.albums.page, warn = FALSE)
```

Also note that you're not 'saving' the tables, it changes at every loop, but maybe that's what you want.